# adaptive sliding window filter

Tags: matlab, image-processing, imagefilter

I want to create an adaptive sliding window filter that operates on a sparse matrix (Image). I want to calculate an average of all pixels with non-zero values within a 9x9 window for each objective pixel with non zero value.  I tried to do it using the following code

```
fun = @(x) mean(x(x~=0));

B = nlfilter(A,[9 9],fun);
```

A is the sparse image to be filtered. The code runs but returns a non zero value for elements that have a zero pixel value in the unfiltered sparse image.  I also want to make sure that to calculate the average for an objective pixel, a minimum of 5 non-zero samples are present within the window. If this is not possible, I want to keep expanding the sliding window until this is fulfilled.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at [spfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spfun.html)?

Comment: Ok spfun may work for preserving the sparsity. Thank you for your suggestion. What about having enough samples to average?